# Split string by line breaks, keeping quoted segments

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have a csv file that is read into a string, and I need to separate that string by line breaks keeping quoted segments. The reason the quotes are being used is because some fields of the file have line breaks within.

Basically, I have a file that is like this (I'm using | to represent the separator):

> This is | a | line
>
> This is | a line too | "but this field has
>
> a line break"
>
> This is | another | line

I know I can use a regex with the `.split()` function, but I'm having trouble with it. Can anyone help?

I'm expecting a array like
`["This is | a | line", "This is | a line too | but this field has\na line break", "This is | another | line"]`

Comment: why does your 2nd example output element have a line break, because it's quoted? in that case, it's simpler to replace the quoted newline with a placeholder, then split by lines, then replace all the placeholders with escaped new lines.

Comment: Some fields have line breaks, and when I generate a file, if I don't use quotes for those specific fields, the programs reading the CSV (excel, libreoffice...) won't recognize this a single field

Comment: check my answer below. I can add explanation if it works for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a simplest solution, **we can first mark(replace with some identifier) the `line breaks`** that we would not want to **split at**.

Then split at all other line breaks and **finally replace the preserved break identifiers** with `line breaks again`(\n)`.`

```
arr = str.replace(/("[\s\S]*?")/g, (m, cg) => {
        return cg.replace(/\n/g, "LINE-BREAK-TO-PRESERVE");
      })
      .split('\n')
      .filter(i => Boolean(i.trim()))
      .map(i => i.replace(/LINE-BREAK-TO-PRESERVE/g, '\n'));
```

Above code should fill your purpose smoothly :)

Comment: It doesn't work completely (the ```replace()``` works on the first quoted field, but then after that it replaces every line break after that - I think the problem is that is more than one quoted field with line breaks in my case) but your answer points to a good direction! Thanks :)

Comment: Heyy @liara . There was just minor typo.  quote matcher had to be non-greedy. I made the change. Please check if it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly this is a simple enough problem that even regex seems like overkill.  I would just iterate through the string, and whenever you find a line break and aren't inside a quote, push the substring that you've found so far onto the array:

```js
var arr = []
var inQuote = false;
var str = `This is | a | line
This is | a line too | "but this field has
a line break"
This is | another | line`
for (var pos = 0; pos < str.length; pos++) {
    if (str.charAt(pos) == "\n" && !inQuote) {
        arr.push(str.slice(0, pos));
        str = str.slice(pos + 1);
        pos = 0;
    } else if (str.charAt(pos) == '"') {
        inQuote = !inQuote;
        // if you want to get rid of the quotes:
        str = str.slice(0, pos) + str.slice(pos + 1)
        pos--
    }
}
arr.push(str)
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this;

```
("[^"\n]*)\r?\n(?!(([^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)
```

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/wL9sQ4/82

Comment: Didn't work :/
I was trying something like ```/(.*".*|\n")|(.*\n)/g``` but it didn't work either

Answer (score -1):

As in another answer, it may be better to use a loop because even with the knowledge of the separator, it is hard to check if the quote is in the middle of data (as a literal) or the quote is acting as a quote.

That said, this regex should serve the purpose for the given case:

```
/(?<!\|\s+"[\w\s]+)\n/
```

```
console.log(
`This is | a | line
This is | a line too | "but this field has
a line break"
This is | another | line`.split(/(?<!\|\s+"[\w\s]+)\n/)
)
```

`?<!` is negative lookbehind, which means the part not in the bracket (`\n`) is matched only when the part in the bracket is *not* matched.

The part in the bracket is Separator (`|`) followed by more than 1 space `\s+` immediately followed by a quote `"` and then followed by a mixture of words and spaces.

Hope this helps.  `\s+` can be modified to `\s*` and `[\w\s]+` may also be changed to `[^"]*` as desired.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wL9sQ4/83)